# Run selenium webdriver script using javascript code

Tags: html, selenium

Is there any way to Run selenium webdriver script (written in eclipse) using javascript code i.e by clicking on html button,, can i run selenium script. Any idea.?

Comment: Written in Eclipse means Java?

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: not necessarily, eclipse can be used for other languages other than Java @SergeyLitvinov `:)`

Comment: @sircapsalot yep, i know it :) but java is one of the post popular, so it was my first guess just to understand what OP asks:)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby

`driver.execute_script("JAVSCRIPT HERE")`

C#

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string something = (string)js.ExecuteScript("JAVASCRIPT");
```

I guess java and C# will be similar.